# collapse staggered records to a single row for repeating keys

Tags: sql

I want to collapse table to eliminate values in sql but the table has repeating keys. For example, I want to collapse this:

```
  key1   key2   v1     v2     v3    
  1      A      a      NULL   NULL  
  1      A      NULL   NULL   9     
  1      A      NULL   x      NULL  
  1      A      b      NULL   NULL  
  1      A      NULL   NULL   8     
  1      A      NULL   x      NULL  
  1      A      a      NULL   NULL  
  1      A      NULL   NULL   7     
  1      A      NULL   y      NULL  
  1      A      b      NULL   NULL  
  1      A      NULL   NULL   6     
  1      A      NULL   y      NULL  
  1      B      a      NULL   NULL  
  1      B      NULL   NULL   5     
  1      B      NULL   z      NULL  
  1      B      b      NULL   NULL  
  1      B      NULL   NULL   4     
  1      B      NULL   z      NULL  
  1      C      a      NULL   NULL  
  1      C      NULL   NULL   10    
  1      C             z      NULL  
  1      C      b      NULL   NULL  
  1      C      NULL   NULL   11    
  1      C      NULL   z      NULL
```

into this:

```
  key1   key2   v1   v2   v3  
  1      A      a    x    9   
  1      A      b    x    8   
  1      A      a    y    7   
  1      A      b    y    6   
  1      B      a    z    5   
  1      B      b    z    4   
  1      C      a    z    10  
  1      C      b    z    11
```

Aggregate functions don't work and I haven't had success with self-join. Any idea?

Comment: How do you know which values go with which values?  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Also what database are you using?

Comment: Is there an auto-increment column in this table?

Comment: I'm using hive. I got the initial table with nulls using hive pivot with case statement (without aggregate function for the same reason).

Comment: Supply the query you used to get the first result.

Comment: The query to get the first table is: select key1, key2, 
case when col = 'v1' then value end as v1,
case when col = 'v2' then value end as v2,
case when col = 'v3' then value end as v3
from mytable
order by key, key2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a key/value table. This is something we usually avoid, but sometimes it cannot be avoided. Your original table looks something like this:

```
key1   key2  col   value
1      A     v1    a
1      A     v1    a
1      A     v1    a
1      A     v1    a
1      A     v1    b
1      A     v1    b
1      A     v1    b
1      A     v1    b
1      A     v2    x
1      A     v2    x
1      A     v2    y
1      A     v2    y
...
```

I am showing the rows in another order then your query result, but that doesn't matter, for a table has no inherent order; it contains the data as an unordered set. We can see that for the same key 1|A|v1  the table contains diifferent values (four times 'a', four times 'b'). This is unexpected. Usually key value tables show *one* value per key.

So it may be that there is something wrong with your data model. Or the table has more columns, e.g. a date to show history data and also enable us to select the current value for 1|A|v1. Then you'd have to change your original query to take this into account. Or that data model *is* correct and 1|A|v1 does have four 'a' and four 'b', but then your expected query result makes no sense, for there is nothing to relate v1='a' to v2='x' for instance.

So something *is* wrong: datamodel, existing query, desired result. Find out which.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "select distinct"

```
 Select distinct key1, key2, v1, v2, v3
 From SomeTable
```

Comment: Doesn't look like it's making any change to the first table.

Comment: Then answer the question by Gordon Linoff above. How do you know which non-null values align with each other?  Seems arbitrary or you have not revealed enough information.